# Norm inequality for solution of ODE realted to eigenvalues of symetric matrix.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symmetric-matrices

I need help with the following problem:

Let $A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix, and $\Lambda, \lambda$ the biggest and smallest eigenvalues respectively. Let $x$ be a solution for $x'=Ax$. Prove that for all $t>0$:

$||x(0)||^2e^{2\lambda t} \leq ||x(t)||^2 \leq ||x(0)||^2e^{2\Lambda t}$ with the euclidean norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first develop a few useful and germane properties of the matrix $A$:

Since $A$ is symmetric, there exists an orthogonal matrix $O$ which diagonalizes $A$, and we have

$D = O^TAO, \tag 1$

where

$O^TO = OO^T = I, \tag 2$

and

$D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n), \tag 3$

with the $\lambda_i \in \Bbb R$ being the eigenvalues of $A$.  Writing $O$ in columnar form,

$O = [\vec e_1 \; \vec e_2 \; \ldots \; \vec e_n], \tag 4$

it follows that

$O^T = \begin{bmatrix} \vec e_1^T \\ \vec e_2^T \\ \vdots \\ \vec e_n^T \end{bmatrix}, \tag 5$

and it is easy to see that (2), (4), (5) imply

$\vec e_i \cdot \vec e_j = \delta_{ij}, \tag 6$

which shows that the columns $\vec e_i$ of $O$ (and hence the rows of $O^T$) form a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$; from (1),

$OD = OO^TAO = IAO = AO, \tag 7$

and it follows *via* (3) that

$AO = A[\vec e_1 \; \vec e_2 \; \ldots \; \vec e_n] =  [A\vec e_1 \; A\vec e_2 \; \ldots \; A\vec e_n]  = OD$
$=  [\vec e_1 \; \vec e_2 \; \ldots \; \vec e_n]\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n)= [\lambda_1 \vec e_1 \; \lambda_2 \vec e_2 \; \ldots \; \lambda_n \vec e_n], \tag 8$

which is easily seen to be equivalent to

$A \vec e_i = \lambda_i \vec e_i, \; 1 \le i \le n. \tag 9$

We turn now to the equation linear, constant-coefficient ordinary differential equation

$\dot x(t) = Ax(t); \tag{10}$

with initial condition $x(0)$ at $t = 0$ the well-known solution is

$x(t) = e^{At}x(0); \tag{11}$

we expand $x(0)$ in terms of the $\vec e_i$

$x(0) = \displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i(0) \vec e_i, \tag{12}$

and substitute this into (11):

$x(t) = e^{At} \displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i(0) \vec e_i = \sum_1^n x_i(0)e^{At} \vec e_i; \tag{13}$

by virtue of (9),

$A^2 \vec e_i = A(A\vec e_i) = A(\lambda_i \vec e_i) = \lambda_i A \vec e_i = \lambda_i(\lambda_i \vec e_i) = \lambda_i^2 \vec e_i, \tag{14}$

and if we assume that

$A^k \vec e_i = \lambda_i^k \vec e_1 \tag{15}$

for some

$2 \le k \in \Bbb N, \tag{16}$

then

$A^{k + 1} \vec e_i = AA^k \vec e_i = A(\lambda_i^k \vec e_i) = \lambda_i^k A\vec e_i = \lambda_i^k \lambda_i \vec e_i = \lambda_i^{k + 1} \vec e_i; \tag{17}$

via (9),(14), (15) and (17) we conclude by induction that

$A^n \vec e_i = \lambda_i^n \vec e_i, \; \forall 0 \le n \in \Bbb N; \tag{18}$

then

$e^{At} \vec e_i = \left ( \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{A^n t^n}{n!} \right ) \vec e_i = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{t^n A^n \vec e_i}{n!} =  \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{t^n \lambda_i^n \vec e_i}{n!} = \left (\sum_0^\infty \dfrac{t^n \lambda_i^n}{n!} \right ) \vec e_i  = e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i; \tag{19}$

in light of this, (13) yields

$x(t) = e^{At} \displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i(0) \vec e_i = \sum_1^n x_i(0)e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i, \tag{20}$

whence, using (6),

$\Vert x(t) \Vert^2 = \left( \displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i(0) e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i \right ) \cdot \left( \displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i(0) e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i \right )$
$= \displaystyle \sum_{i, j = 1}^n x_i(0)x_j(0) e^{(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)t} \vec e_i \cdot \vec e_j$
$= \displaystyle \sum_{i, j = 1}^n x_i(0)x_j(0) e^{(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)t} \delta_{ij} = \sum_1^n e^{2\lambda_i t} x_i^2(0);  \tag{21}$

since the function $e^{\mu t}$ is monotonically increasing in $\mu$ for $t \ge 0$, (21) yields

$e^{2\lambda t} \Vert x(0) \Vert^2 = e^{2\lambda t}\displaystyle \sum_1^n x_i^2(0) = \sum_1^n e^{2\lambda t} x_i^2(0) \le  \displaystyle \sum_1^n e^{2\lambda_i t} x_i^2(0)$
$= \Vert x(t) \Vert^2 \le \displaystyle \sum_1^n e^{2\Lambda t} x_i^2(0) = e^{2\Lambda t} \sum_1^n x_i^2(0) = e^{2\Lambda t} \Vert x(0) \Vert^2, \tag{22}$

from which we may extract the inequality

$e^{2 \lambda t} \Vert x(0) \Vert^2 \le \Vert x(t) \Vert^2 \le e^{2 \Lambda t} \Vert x(0) \Vert^2, \tag{23}$

which was to be proved.

Comment: first of all really thank you for the answer. I just have one question, why you can write x(0) in that way in (12), the coordinate not has to be the internal product between x(0) and e_i? I dont see why is equal to x_i(0).

Comment: That equation basically *defines* $x_i(0)$ in the $\vec e_i$ basis; since the $\vec e_i$ form an orthonormal basis, we have $x_i(0) = x(0) \cdot \vec e_i$.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure about that. Thank you for the extra explanation.

Comment: @PeterLanguilla:  No problem my friend.  And thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers!